# bluetooth indicator and other settings not working after updating kernel to 3.16

Tags: kernel, updates, bluetooth, indicator

So, today there was this update for the Kernel to 3.16 on LTSEnablementStack. I ran the command for the update. I notice that a lot of packages are removed, like the bluetooth indicator, but it seems like there is no replacement for it. Appart from this a lot of things doesn't work anymore: system-settings, unity-control-center.

I tried to install univety-control-center again and it asked me to install a lot of dependency. Finally I had to install all the things below

```
sudo apt-get install unity-control-center libcheese-gtk23 libcheese7 libclutter-1.0-0 libcogl-pango15 libcogl15 libgbm1 libgl1-mesa-dri
```

But then the last one "libgl1-mesa-dri will ask me to remove everything I got from the kernel update!!!
Any help to let me install at least system-settings and bluetooth indicator while I keep the kernel 3.16?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My only solution to my own question is to revert back to the old setup.

First thins is to uninstall the kernel 3.16 with (replace the version to the right one)

> sudo apt-get purge linux-image-3.4.0-* linux-headers-3.4.0-*

Second thing is to remove everything which brought the problem

> sudo apt-get purge linux-generic-lts-utopic xserver-xorg-lts-utopic libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-utopic libegl1-mesa-drivers-lts-utopic

Finally, install the old version of these removed things with

> sudo apt-get install --install-recommends linux-generic xserver-xorg libgl1-mesa-glx libegl1-mesa-drivers